# How can I delete rows in Excel that exist in Access?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a table called "ActiveCustomers" in an Access DB which contains customer names and telephone numbers. I also have an Excel sheet which contains the same data in my "ActiveCustomers" table in Access, plus Inactive Customers. I would like to delete from the Excel sheet all the Active Customers that exist in the Access DB, leaving only the inactive customers in the sheet. What do I need to do in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify Excel sheets linked to an Access database, [only read](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=904953) from them.

Therefore I'd recommend importing the data you have in the sheet, use a query to generate the information you need and then export that to a new spread sheet.

Although I don't see why you are maintaining the inactive customers in an external sheet when you have a database? Simply record the information in the database and stop using the Excel sheet.

Comment: That's what I told my client, to store both active and inactive customers in the Access table and add a status field, but he said the inactive's are about 15 million rows and his Access started choking.

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom - If you are up to 15m rows I'd suggest moving to a larger database (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.) and store all the data in one place rather than cobbling together systems using Access and Excel. In answer to your question about the import/export solution I don't see that working if Access is struggling with the size of the data set. You may be better off exporting the active characters to another sheet in Excel and performing the delete there, but that's still not optimal.

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom so for ~15 million inactives I guess you're talking about *several* Excel sheets since one sheet is limited to 1048576 rows.

Comment: row size is small (40 chars) just name and phone number, but apparently ~15M rows is too much for the ACE engine to handle.. correct on multiple excel sheets. I don't know much more about the setup. The telemarketing person asked me if I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from another answer, for a table with two fields:

```
[CustomerName] - Text(30), Not Indexed  
[PhoneNumber]  - Text(10), Indexed (Duplicates OK)
```

15 million rows that are completely full (40 characters each), e.g.

```
CustomerName                    PhoneNumber
------------------------------  -----------
Inactive Customer No: 00000001  9900000001
Inactive Customer No: 00000002  9900000002
Inactive Customer No: 00000003  9900000003
...
Inactive Customer No: 15000000  9915000000
```

results in an 982 MB .accdb file, which is 48% of the 2 GB maximum .accdb file size.

So, with some care, it should be possible to import the inactive records from all of the Excel sheets into an Access database file and process then *en masse*.

Depending on what is already in the "main" Access database file it might be prudent to import the inactive records into a separate .accdb file and then create a Linked Table into the main .accdb file to access the active records.

Comment: I simulated this scenario by importing into Access 2010/ACE, 15 million rows of names and phone numbers from registered voters in the State of Florida. Then I created a dups index on phone number and did some queries like select all inactive voters, etc. Although Access has a 2GB limit, the performance of my scenario was unacceptable, and I have a modern 64-bit computer with 6GB ram, 1TB disk!

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom If your queries were unable to use indexes on the fields in the WHERE clause then yes, a table scan of 15 million rows is going to be rather slow.

Comment: Well, SELECT name FROM voters WHERE name like "FRANK%"; was slow!

Comment: Do you have an index on the [name] field? If not, then you're doing a table scan.

Comment: Of course, I even included a "ActiveStatus" Yes/No field, indexed it, ran SELECT telnum FROM voters WHERE "ActiveStatus" = TRUE; and it was still slow!

Comment: I don't know what you're doing differently, but when I do `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Customers WHERE ActiveStatus=True` in Access and there's no index on [ActiveStatus] it takes ~23 seconds to scan through all 15 million rows. After adding an index on [ActiveStatus] that same query consistently takes 0.04 seconds to execute.

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways of making an access table;

import, link, and so on..

if you selected "IMPORT" when making the table of the data from excel,
  just delete the table and re-make the table.

if you selected "Link from Excel",
  close the access table ( NOT Access program itself, just table is enough).
  and just delete the data from Excel file.

- HOW TO FIGURE IT OUT, IMPORT OR LINK? *
  If the table imported from an Excel file is open and you try to open the linked Excel file, Excel alerts you, saying that something wrong.

  If so, the table is directly linked from Excel. go to the excel file and revise it.

Comment: I was hoping that I could link the excel sheet to the access db and run an SQL-delete statement like: DELETE FROM sheet WHERE sheet.telnum IN (SELECT telnum FROM AccessTable)?

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom - Unfortunately not. There's a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=904953) stating you cannot modify data, which also seems to apply to Office 2010. This was due to [a legal case Microsoft lost](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2005/06/07/microsoft_pays_excel_man/) .

Comment: So, you're best suggestion is to import the sheet data into a new access table, run the SQL-delete and export the table back to a new sheet?